# How can I connect a SwiftUI TextField to a NSManagedObject property?

Tags: nsmanagedobject, swiftui

I want to create a view allowing the user to edit a single NSManagedObject entity like below.

```
class Employee: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}

struct EditEmpView : View {
     @ObservedObject var empToEdit: Employee

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $empToEdit.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366803/binding-core-data-object-to-input-swiftui